# Detect checked user permissions in view rendering, output within the HTTP response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC website that has a custom permission system. When user calls a controller method I retrieve his permissions from the DB and store them in a object that I pass to view rendering.

In the view I render only some parts of the content (based on the permissions). I would like to add an output to the footer.

> You have *Permission1*, *Permission2* that are checked on this page. You
>   are missing **Permission3**.

Questions:

1. What is the appropriate http-request limited scope where I can keep a list of used permissions and add to it during the rendering?
2. Can I modify the finished HTML output after all the child actions are rendered?

   2.1. I assume that this would be in the _Layout view after `@RenderBody()` is executed?

Comment: Do not think about `http-request`. I prefer to create `BaseViewModel` class, which will be consist `permissions-object`or some permission attributes. To create `ViewModel` class (inherited BaseViewModel) for each `View`. Then via `@if` in the View show/hide `<div> etc`.

Comment: As far as I know the view model approach has 2 problems: 1) It is limited to controller-action pair. If I render subaction from another controller it will be a different controller thus a different instance although the base would be the same. 2) ViewModel is not available in the Layout view (where I would like to output the results)